# DevExpress XtraGrid GroupRow, CheckEdit Interactions Possibilities

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

Currently, I am displaying an XtraGrid that contains Group Rows. I have a "Select All" DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckEdit control (which is different from this elusive "Select All" check box control I am reading about in the documentation). It is different for a reason: I want the check box to do something other than "Select All" (which comes in only three different varieties according to the DevExpress Docs.).

I want a user to be able to do one of two things with the CheckEdit control. [1] If no Group Rows are expanded, I want to select all Group Rows. [2] If one or more Group Rows are expanded, I only want to select the expanded rows.

Presently, I am able to manipulate the controls to do only one of the two things (see code). My question is twofold: is this possible; and, if so, how would I go about it?

Here is my code that does the second of the two 'things' described above:

```
'If the CheckEdit control is checked:  

xtraGrid.SelectAll()

Dim rowHandles() As Int32 = xtraGrid.GetSelectedRows()  

If rowHandles.Count > 0 Then
    For Each RowHandle As Int32 In rowHandles
        If xtraGrid.IsGroupRow(RowHandle) Then
            xtraGrid.UnselectRow(RowHandle)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

As you can see, all this really is just a work around. There is also presumably more overhead than needed in my calling `.GetSelectedRows()`. I am just attempting to sort through the row types in order to keep the row selected or `.UnselectRow()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.GetRowExpanded`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowExpandedtopic) method to check whether a specific group row is expanded. For iterating through visible rows you can use [`GridView.RowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCounttopic) property. To get row level just use [`GridView.GetRowLevel`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowLeveltopic) method. Also you need to check wether a row is new item row or is filter row by using [`GridView.IsNewItemRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_IsNewItemRowtopic) method and [`GridView.IsFilterRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_IsFilterRowtopic) method. For all of this methods you need to get `Row handle` by using [`GridView.GetVisibleRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetVisibleRowHandletopic) method. When you are working with selection is better to use [`GridView.BeginSelection`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_BeginSelectiontopic) method and [`GridView.EndSelection`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_EndSelectiontopic) method outside of your code.
**UPDATE:** If you want to select hidden rows within a collapsed group then you can use [`GridView.GetChildRowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetChildRowCounttopic) method and [`GridView.GetChildRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetChildRowHandletopic) method to get all hidden rows.
Here is some sample code that is performing your two things together:

```
Private Sub SomeSub

    If xtraGrid.GroupCount = 0 Then
        xtraGrid.SelectAll()

        Exit Sub
    End If

    xtraGrid.BeginSelection()
    xtraGrid.ClearSelection()

    Dim isExpanded As Boolean = False

    For rowVisibleIndex = 0 To xtraGrid.RowCount - 1
        Dim rowHandle As Integer = xtraGrid.GetVisibleRowHandle(rowVisibleIndex)

        If xtraGrid.IsNewItemRow(rowHandle) Then
            Continue For
        End If

        Dim level As Integer = xtraGrid.GetRowLevel(rowHandle)

        If level = 0 Then
            If Not isExpanded Then
                isExpanded = xtraGrid.GetRowExpanded(rowHandle)

                If isExpanded Then
                    xtraGrid.ClearSelection()
                Else
                    xtraGrid.SelectRow(rowHandle)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            xtraGrid.SelectRow(rowHandle)

            'Update: select hidden rows
            If xtraGrid.IsGroupRow(rowHandle) And Not xtraGrid.GetRowExpanded(rowHandle) Then
                SelectRowHierarchy(rowHandle)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    xtraGrid.EndSelection()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectRowHierarchy(rowHandle As Integer)

    Dim childCount As Integer = xtraGrid.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle)

    For childIndex As Integer = 0 To childCount - 1

        Dim childRowHandle As Integer = xtraGrid.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, childIndex)

        xtraGrid.SelectRow(childRowHandle)

        If xtraGrid.IsGroupRow(childRowHandle) Then
            SelectRowHierarchy(childRowHandle)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The biggest trouble with this - and it is a great solution you are proposing - is if the possible rows are not visible, i.e. hidden by the context (window) in which the grid is presented. Believe it or not - I think this is the biggest flaw of the `.isVisible()` stuff - if the row is not actually visible, then it isn't selected or manipulable.

Comment: @Thomas In DevExpress if the specified row is hidden within a collapsed group then this row is invisible. Otherwise, the row is considered to be visible. You can check the row visibility by using [`GridView.GetVisibleIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetVisibleIndextopic) method. Do you want to select only those rows that are currently visible in user screen?  Or you want to select rows that are hidden within a collapsed group?

Comment: I would - ideally - like to select all the rows that are currently "visible" as per your definition. Let me play around with it a bit more. I wonder if the control I am using to host the grid is changing the functionality a bit.

Comment: Okay, so your method, barring the `If xtraGrid.GroupCount` bit, essentially accomplishes what mine does, above. Which is good because conceptually we are on the same page (sort of - what we're doing is certainly different, which is fine). Let me refine the initial question a bit: having the ability to select all visible rows, then, how do I select all hidden rows? `.SelectAll()` on collapsed group rows only returns the first row under the group.

Comment: @Thomas You can use `GridView.GetChildRowCount` method and `GridView.GetChildRowHandle` method. Look at updates in my answer.